# Cheese producer

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

1. A cheese producer must feed her stock of Jersey Cattle daily at least 550 units of nutritional element A, 500 units of nutritional element B, and 820 units of nutritional element C. She has Available two feeds. One pound of feed X costs 80 cents and contains 2 units of A, 5 units of B, and 7 units of C. One pound of feed Y costs 30 cents and contains 3 units of A, 1 unit of B, and 2 units of C. The Cheese producer wants to determine what combination of the two feeds will meet the dietary requirements of her Jerseys and keep costs at a minimum. Determine the least expensive adequate feeding diet.
2. Generalize. Suppose feed X costs c1 cents/lb and feed Y costs c2 cents/lb. For what range on the ratio of c1 to c2 would the optimal diet of part (1) remain optimal?
3. In particular, assume that the cost of feed Y is fixed at 30 cents/lb but that the cost of feed X is increasing. By how much can this cost increase before the diet of part (1) is no longer optimal? If the Cost of feed X increases by more than this bound, what would be the new optimal diet?
4. Determine the resolution of the original problem with the added restriction that no more than 215 lbs of feed X may be used in the daily diet.

I have figured out part 1, that the optimal solution is (60 units of feed X, 200 of feed Y). But I am unclear on how to do the rest, especially part (2). If needed the other possible solutions were (0, 500), (80, 160), (275, 0)